# Connecting multiple dds-discovery-servers between each other

Tags: ros2, dds

I am trying to get the following setup by command line, but it is not working (Ros2, Galactic, fastrtps): I would like to setup a set of ROS2 nodes partitioned by multiple discovery servers. I would like to have these discovery-servers on different machines but at the moment let's take the topology of option2 of [this document](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/use_cases/wifi/discovery_server_use_case.html), so consider just one machine.
***We have 2 discovery server (DS1 and DS2) with a publisher (P)  referring to DS1 and a subscriber (S) referring to DS2:   P -> DS1 <-> DS2 <- S.*** My question is "Can I get the servers talking to each other from  command line"? According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/EduPonz/5f71532154cc708d0f41e8896e097f5b#run-demo-with-net-host) , if I got it right, it is possible prefixing to one of the servers the reference to the other via "export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER" (so one server becomes a "client" of the other). All in all, I have the following configuration:

```
TERMINAL1 (DS1):
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.sh
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
fastdds discovery -i 0 -l 192.168.1.188 -p 11811

TERMINAL2 (DS2):
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.sh
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811"
fastdds discovery -i 1 -l 192.168.1.188 -p 11812

TERMINAL3 (P)
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server


TERMINAL4 (S):

source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.sh
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11812"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server
```

If this can not be achieved via shell commands, to my understanding I can take point to an xml config file (like [this](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/use_cases/wifi/discovery_server_use_case.html#option-2)) via FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE, but then how should I use it? With one server I would just launch "fastdds discovery -i 0" but here there are multiples..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution ([here](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/v2.1.0/fastdds/env_vars/env_vars.html#ros-discovery-server) for details): when setting the ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER environmental variable one needs to specify the IP address in the "right slot". So each IP address needs to match the corresponding discovery server id: below a working example with discovery servers on  different machines:

```
MACHINE1-TERMINAL1 (discovery server '0'):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811"
fastdds discovery -i 0 -l 192.168.1.188 -p 11811

MACHINE1-TERMINAL2 (discovery server '1'):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811;192.168.1.188:11812;"
fastdds discovery -i 1 -l 192.168.1.188 -p 11812

MACHINE1-TERMINAL3 (talker via server '1'):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=";192.168.1.188:11812;"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server

MACHINE1-TERMINAL4 (listener via server '0'):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811;;"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server

MACHINE2-TERMINAL1 (discovery server '2'):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="192.168.1.188:11811;;192.168.1.248:11813"
fastdds discovery -i 2 -l 192.168.1.248 -p 11813

MACHINE2-TERMINAL2 (listener on MACHINE2):
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=";;192.168.1.248:11813;"
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server
```

However sometimes one of the listener doesn't output anything till I restart the 'related' discovery server: is there an error in the above example or  how should one detect/cope with such behaviors when for example working out in the field?

Thanks